# AngularJs pagination issue - not able to pass new filtered number of objects

Tags: angularjs, pagination

I am trying to make a football scores project for practice using angularjs. In the project, There is a checkbox named "2015" which will show only matches and scores for 2015 year only if it is checked. Now since data is reduced to 2015 year only then it creates problem in pagination because pagination divides the number of pages with previous unfiltered data only and shows blank pages. How can i pass the new reduced/filtered number of data to pagination so it will divide the pages correctly...
Here is the download link of angularjs project : http://www55.zippyshare.com/v/B36KXZ16/file.html

I think the problem is with this line number 5 in "all.html" :

```
<div class="table-responsive" dir-paginate="data in vm.rounds.concat(vm.rounds1) | itemsPerPage:10" class="col-12 text-center" ng-if="isChecked2015">
```

Here 
vm.rounds.concat(vm.rounds1) is unfiltered all data and the problem in pagination comes when the data is filtered and reduced so if there is a function which can calculate the number of data(after 2015 is checked) and then tell the pagination to use the new total number of items to loop through then problem can be solved and there will be no blank pages in pagination, please tell me if there is any way to achieve it.

Thank You

Comment: Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rather than having us look through an entire project

Comment: Sorry i have edited the question with the problem and possible solution...

Comment: @Farhan did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @ShashanSooriyahetti No, i removed the pagination. That was a practice project so it was not necessary.